# Select random values from each group, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project through which I'm creating a game powered by a database.

The database has data entered like this:

(ID, Name) || (1, PhotoID),(1,PhotoID),(1,PhotoID),(2,PhotoID),(2,PhotoID) and so on. There are thousands of entries.

This is my current SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 8 * FROM Image WHERE Hidden = '0' ORDER BY NEWID()";
```

But this can also produce results with matching IDs, where I need to have each result have a unique ID (that is I need one result from each group).

How can I change my query to grab one result from each group?

Thanks!

Comment: Test schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ORDER BY NEWID()` will result in tablescan anyway, you might use row_number() to isolate first in group:

```
; with randomizer as (
  select id,
         name,
         row_number() over (partition by id
                            order by newid()) rn
    from Image
   where hidden = 0
)
select top 8
       id,
       name
  from randomizer
 where rn = 1
-- Added by mellamokb's suggestion to allow groups to be randomized
order by newid()
```

[Sql Fiddle playground](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657ad/15) thanks to mellamokb.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to randomize the overall groups.  Wonder if  throwing another `order by newid()` on the final query would fix it? **EDIT:** Ya that seems to do it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657ad/14

Comment: @mellamokb I was rather under impression that number 8 in top corresponds to number of groups because it is a game and I would expect a slot for each image group. I know that this is figment of my imagination though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this may work, but I can't vouch for performance:

```
SELECT TOP 8 ID,
  (select top 1 name from image i2
   where i2.id = i1.id order by newid())
FROM Image i1
WHERE hidden = '0'
group by ID
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657ad/6

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on the `ID` column and want to take advantage of the index and avoid a full table scan, do your randomization on the key values first:

```
WITH IDs AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM Image
  WHERE Hidden = '0'
),
SequencedIDs AS
(
  SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Seq
  FROM IDs
),
ImageGroups AS
(
  SELECT i.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ID ORDER BY NEWID()) Seq
  FROM SequencedIDs s
  INNER JOIN Image i
    ON i.ID = s.ID
  WHERE s.Seq < 8
  AND i.Hidden = '0'
)
SELECT *
FROM ImageGroups
WHERE Seq = 1
```

This should drastically reduce the cost over the table scan approach, although I don't have a schema big enough that I can test with - so try running some statistics in SSMS and make sure `ID` is actually indexed for this to be effective.

Comment: Note - in the [sqlfiddle sandbox](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cfc7/1) this is significantly cheaper than [mellamokb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11750069/38360) and only slightly higher than [Nikola's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11750090/38360) - however, the sample size is extremely small, and I believe this would perform better on a very large number of rows because it does not need to scan them all - only 1 row per initial group and all rows for the much smaller top N random groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (select * from photos order by rand()) as _SUB group by _SUB.id;
```

Comment: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657ad/9

Comment: @mellamokb everything is allowed in the world of mysql, yet i just noticed, sql-server is the tag... my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select ID, Name from (select ID, Name, row_number() over 
 (partition by ID, Name order by ID) as ranker from Image where Hidden = 0 ) Z where ranker = 1
 order by newID()
```